# Java Double formatting String output

Tags: java, double, decimal

I'm having some problem formatting decimals of a double. The only error is:
String output = DecimalFormat = (((P * t) / 360) * 0.025);

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(" ###,###.00");
String output = DecimalFormat = (((P * t) / 360) * 0.025);
```

Comment: "I'm having some problem formatting decimals of a double" which?

Comment: Main.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
        String output = DecimalFormat = (((P * t) / 360) * 0.025);
  symbol:   variable DecimalFormat

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00");
String output = df.format(((30 * 45) / 360) * 0.025);
```

In your second line, you have `DecimalFormat =` which should be replaced with `df.format` The `DecimalFormat` class doesn't let you format decimals, it's the `df` object that you created which can format decimals by calling the `format` method.